# Unknown provider for $modalStackProvider while including ui-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use ui-bootstrap for Tabs in my application keeping the example on ui-bootstrap's website as reference. For the same I included the js files given in the exapmle which are: 
[Angular.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js), [Animate.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js), [Sanitize.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js) and [BootStrap-tpls.js](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.3.0.js)

But after including these JS Files I'm shown an error:
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalStackProvider <- $modalStack

I'm not able to resolve this dependency.

Comment: Please follow the latest documentation provided by ui-bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

You have some version mismatch.
It used to be $modal, $modalInstance, etc. in old Angular Bootstrap.
Now it is $uibModal, $uibModalInstance, etc.

So check versions of libraries that depends on Angular Bootstrap.